# VBA Code to call a sub within a Userform from outside the Userform

Tags: excel, vba

Please see my comments below, I couldn't see a 'reply' button to the individual comments left, therefore I am going to amend this main feed to read latest information that I requiere help.guidance on.

I am new to VBA but learning more each day, I have a rate calc created and with in it are 2 userforms created `CFSCollectionAir` & `CFSCollectionOcean`, which when invoked, the user can input various information and then upon saving/closing the Userform, said information is saved to a worksheet tab called `FormsControl Sheet`.

When I run the sub routine from within the Forms module, all works great, menu pops up, I can input data, close form and said data is copied/stored in `FormsControl Sheet`, this bit I have done successfully.

My issues is I wish call the sub `CFSCollectionAir` when a certain cell in excel is selected, I have a drop down with 2 lines `Factory Load` & `CFS Loading`, when the user selects `CFS Loading`, I wish to call my `Sub CFSCollectionAir`, users inputs the data in the menu, closes sub via the close button and then we return back to the excel sheet.

I have now successfully managed to call the sub from my main page, however, if I run the sub by directly clicking F5, all works fine but when the same sub is 'called' within another sub, all appears to run fine except nothing is saved off, it does save if run directly using f5 key

Below is the whole code

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim r As Range, rMode As Range, rLane As Range, rLoading As Range
    
    Set r = Target.Cells(1, 1)  'only check first cell
    Set rMode = Range("C3")
    Set rLane = Range("C4")
    Set rLoading = Range("C5")
            
    If r.Address <> rMode.Address And r.Address <> rLane.Address And r.Address <> rLoading.Address Then Exit Sub    '   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    If Len(r.Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub


    'Step 1 - configure
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True      '   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Unprotect Password:="dlm"


    If Target.Address = rMode.Address Then rLane.Value = "Please Select Origin..."
        
    Shapes("RFR20").Visible = False
    Shapes("RFR40").Visible = False
    Shapes("RFR40HQ").Visible = False
    Shapes("Priority20").Visible = False
    Shapes("Priority40").Visible = False
    Shapes("Priority40HQ").Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("RFR20").Object.Value = False
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("RFR40").Object.Value = False
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("RFR40HQ").Object.Value = False
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Priority20").Object.Value = False
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Priority40").Object.Value = False
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Priority40HQ").Object.Value = False
    'ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("RFR20").Value = xlOff
    
    Rows("5:25").Hidden = True
    Rows("79:81").Hidden = True
    Rows("87:" & Rows.Count).Hidden = False
   
'  step 2 - based on Mode, select Lane and configure
    Select Case rMode.Value
        Case "Air"      '   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Mode = Air
            Select Case rLane.Value
                Case "Warsaw to New York"
                    rLoading.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    If rLoading.Value = "CFS Loading" Then
                    Call CallCFSAirMacro
                    Range("C8:C10").Value = vbNullString
                    Range("C11:C17").Value = vbNullString
                    Range("C19:C21").Value = vbNullString
                    Range("A5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Range("A6").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Range("A7:A8").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Range("A9:A11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Range("A12:A16").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Range("A17").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Range("A18:A21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Range("A23:A25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Range("A32").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Range("A33:A76").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    If Range("M29") = False Then Rows("33:77").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Else
                    Range("C8:C10").Value = vbNullString
                    Range("C11:C17").Value = vbNullString
                    Range("C19:C21").Value = vbNullString
                    Range("A5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Range("A6").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Range("A7:A8").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Range("A9:A11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Range("A12:A16").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Range("A17").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Range("A18:A21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Range("A23:A25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    Range("A32").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Range("A33:A76").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    If Range("M29") = False Then Rows("33:77").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    End If
                    
End Sub~~~~

Below is at the end of my main code above and I tried to use that to call the sub within the forms module
~~~~vba
Public Sub CallCFSAirMacro()
        CFSCollectionAir.Show
        'Unload CFSCollectionAir
        Call CFSCollectionAir.SaveButtonAir_Click
        
End Sub~~~~

The sub `SaveButtonAir_Click` is in the forms module and consist of the below code
~~~~vba
Public Sub SaveButtonAir_Click()

'Declare variables
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cb7Air As ComboBox
Dim cb8Air As ComboBox
Dim cb93Air As ComboBox
Dim cb10Air As ComboBox
Dim cb11Air As ComboBox
Dim cb12Air As ComboBox
Dim CartonstrText1Air As String
Dim CartonstrText2Air As String
Dim CartonstrText3Air As String
Dim CartonstrText4Air As String
Dim CartonstrText5Air As String
Dim CartonstrText6Air As String
Dim WeightstrText1Air As String
Dim WeightstrText2Air As String
Dim WeightstrText3Air As String
Dim WeightstrText4Air As String
Dim WeightstrText5Air As String
Dim WeightstrText6Air As String
Dim CBMstrText1Air As String
Dim CBMstrText2Air As String
Dim CBMstrText3Air As String
Dim CBMstrText4Air As String
Dim CBMstrText5Air As String
Dim CBMstrText6Air As String

'Get the text from the textbox
' Set variables
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("FormsControl Sheet")
Set cb7Air = Me.CFSCollectionAir1
Set cb8Air = Me.CFSCollectionAir2
Set cb9Air = Me.CFSCollectionAir3
Set cb10Air = Me.CFSCollectionAir4
Set cb11Air = Me.CFSCollectionAir5
Set cb12Air = Me.CFSCollectionAir6
CartonstrText1Air = Carton1Air.Text
CartonstrText2Air = Carton2Air.Text
CartonstrText3Air = Carton3Air.Text
CartonstrText4Air = Carton4Air.Text
CartonstrText5Air = Carton5Air.Text
CartonstrText6Air = Carton6Air.Text
PalletstrText1Air = Pallet1Air.Text
PalletstrText2Air = Pallet2Air.Text
PalletstrText3Air = Pallet3Air.Text
PalletstrText4Air = Pallet4Air.Text
PalletstrText5Air = Pallet5Air.Text
PalletstrText6Air = Pallet6Air.Text
WeightstrText1Air = Weight1Air.Text
WeightstrText2Air = Weight2Air.Text
WeightstrText3Air = Weight3Air.Text
WeightstrText4Air = Weight4Air.Text
WeightstrText5Air = Weight5Air.Text
WeightstrText6Air = Weight6Air.Text
CBMstrText1Air = CBM1Air.Text
CBMstrText2Air = CBM2Air.Text
CBMstrText3Air = CBM3Air.Text
CBMstrText4Air = CBM4Air.Text
CBMstrText5Air = CBM5Air.Text
CBMstrText6Air = CBM6Air.Text


'Set the destination worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Worksheets("FormsControl Sheet")

'Copy the text to cells in Sheet FormsControl Sheet

ws.Range("B25").Value = cb7Air.Value
ws.Range("B27").Value = cb8Air.Value
ws.Range("B29").Value = cb9Air.Value
ws.Range("B31").Value = cb10Air.Value
ws.Range("B33").Value = cb11Air.Value
ws.Range("B35").Value = cb12Air.Value
ws.Range("D25").Value = CartonstrText1Air
ws.Range("D27").Value = CartonstrText2Air
ws.Range("D29").Value = CartonstrText3Air
ws.Range("D31").Value = CartonstrText4Air
ws.Range("D33").Value = CartonstrText5Air
ws.Range("D35").Value = CartonstrText6Air
ws.Range("F25").Value = PalletstrText1Air
ws.Range("F27").Value = PalletstrText2Air
ws.Range("F29").Value = PalletstrText3Air
ws.Range("F31").Value = PalletstrText4Air
ws.Range("F33").Value = PalletstrText5Air
ws.Range("F35").Value = PalletstrText6Air
ws.Range("H25").Value = WeightstrText1Air
ws.Range("H27").Value = WeightstrText2Air
ws.Range("H29").Value = WeightstrText3Air
ws.Range("H31").Value = WeightstrText4Air
ws.Range("H33").Value = WeightstrText5Air
ws.Range("H35").Value = WeightstrText6Air
ws.Range("J25").Value = CBMstrText1Air
ws.Range("J27").Value = CBMstrText2Air
ws.Range("J29").Value = CBMstrText3Air
ws.Range("J31").Value = CBMstrText4Air
ws.Range("J33").Value = CBMstrText5Air
ws.Range("J35").Value = CBMstrText6Air

'Unload the userform
CFSCollectionAir.Hide
Unload CFSCollectionAir
End Sub
 
Public Sub Carton1Air_Change()
    UpdateCtnsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Carton2Air_Change()
    UpdateCtnsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Carton3Air_Change()
    UpdateCtnsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Carton4Air_Change()
    UpdateCtnsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Carton5Air_Change()
    UpdateCtnsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Carton6Air_Change()
    UpdateCtnsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateCtnsTotalAir()
    'Get the values of the 6 textboxes
    Dim TextBox25Value As Double
    Dim TextBox26Value As Double
    Dim TextBox27Value As Double
    Dim TextBox28Value As Double
    Dim TextBox29Value As Double
    Dim TextBox30Value As Double

    TextBox25Value = Val(Carton1Air.Text)
    TextBox26Value = Val(Carton2Air.Text)
    TextBox27Value = Val(Carton3Air.Text)
    TextBox28Value = Val(Carton4Air.Text)
    TextBox29Value = Val(Carton5Air.Text)
    TextBox30Value = Val(Carton6Air.Text)
       
    'Calculate the total
    Dim Total As Double
    Total = TextBox25Value + TextBox26Value + TextBox27Value + TextBox28Value + TextBox29Value + TextBox30Value

    'Display the total in the total textbox
    TotalCtnsAir.Text = Format(Total, "0")
End Sub

Public Sub Pallet1Air_Change()
UpdatePalletsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Pallet2Air_Change()
UpdatePalletsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Pallet3Air_Change()
UpdatePalletsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Pallet4Air_Change()
UpdatePalletsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Pallet5Air_Change()
UpdatePalletsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Pallet6Air_Change()
UpdatePalletsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub UpdatePalletsTotalAir()
'Get the values of the 6 textboxes
    Dim TextBox31Value As Double
    Dim TextBox32Value As Double
    Dim TextBox33Value As Double
    Dim TextBox34Value As Double
    Dim TextBox35Value As Double
    Dim TextBox36Value As Double

    TextBox31Value = Val(Pallet1Air.Text)
    TextBox32Value = Val(Pallet2Air.Text)
    TextBox33Value = Val(Pallet3Air.Text)
    TextBox34Value = Val(Pallet4Air.Text)
    TextBox35Value = Val(Pallet5Air.Text)
    TextBox36Value = Val(Pallet6Air.Text)

    'Calculate the total
    Dim Total As Double
    Total = TextBox31Value + TextBox32Value + TextBox33Value + TextBox34Value + TextBox35Value + TextBox36Value

    'Display the total in the total textbox
    TotalPalletsAir.Text = Format(Total, "0")
End Sub

Public Sub Weight1Air_Change()
    UpdateWeightsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Weight2Air_Change()
    UpdateWeightsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Weight3Air_Change()
    UpdateWeightsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Weight4Air_Change()
    UpdateWeightsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Weight5Air_Change()
    UpdateWeightsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Weight6Air_Change()
    UpdateWeightsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateWeightsTotalAir()
    'Get the values of the 6 textboxes
    Dim TextBox37Value As Double
    Dim TextBox38Value As Double
    Dim TextBox39Value As Double
    Dim TextBox40Value As Double
    Dim TextBox41Value As Double
    Dim TextBox42Value As Double

    TextBox37Value = Val(Weight1Air.Text)
    TextBox38Value = Val(Weight2Air.Text)
    TextBox39Value = Val(Weight3Air.Text)
    TextBox40Value = Val(Weight4Air.Text)
    TextBox41Value = Val(Weight5Air.Text)
    TextBox42Value = Val(Weight6Air.Text)

    'Calculate the total
    Dim Total As Double
    Total = TextBox37Value + TextBox38Value + TextBox39Value + TextBox40Value + TextBox41Value + TextBox42Value

    'Display the total in the total textbox
    TotalWeightAir.Text = Format(Total, "0")

End Sub

Public Sub CBM1Air_Change()
    UpdateCBMTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub CBM2Air_Change()
    UpdateCBMTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub CBM3Air_Change()
    UpdateCBMTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub CBM4Air_Change()
    UpdateCBMTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub CBM5Air_Change()
    UpdateCBMTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub CBM6Air_Change()
    UpdateCBMTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateCBMTotalAir()
    'Get the values of the 6 textboxes
    Dim TextBox43Value As Double
    Dim TextBox44Value As Double
    Dim TextBox45Value As Double
    Dim TextBox46Value As Double
    Dim TextBox47Value As Double
    Dim TextBox48Value As Double

    TextBox43Value = Val(CBM1Air.Text)
    TextBox44Value = Val(CBM2Air.Text)
    TextBox45Value = Val(CBM3Air.Text)
    TextBox46Value = Val(CBM4Air.Text)
    TextBox47Value = Val(CBM5Air.Text)
    TextBox48Value = Val(CBM6Air.Text)

    'Calculate the total
    Dim Total As Double
    Total = TextBox43Value + TextBox44Value + TextBox45Value + TextBox46Value + TextBox47Value + TextBox48Value

    'Display the total in the total textbox
    TotalCBMAir.Text = Format(Total, "0.00")
End Sub~~~~
```

Comment: If the Sub is private you cannot access it from outside. Create a public sub inside your UserForm. Put the current code inside SaveButtonAir_Click into the public sub. Then you can access it from outside.

Comment: Is the sub `SaveButtonAir_Click` in the forms module Public ?

Comment: `CallCFSAirMacro` sub must be `Public` and it must be called as `UserFormName.CallCFSAirMacro`.

Comment: `Private Sub CallCFSAirMacro()` is OK if it is located below the `Public Sub Worksheet_Change()` where it is called in `Case "Warsaw to New York"`. It's the sub `SaveButtonAir_Click` that must be Public.

Comment: You have the worksheet_change event as public, it will only work in the worksheet module and is private. It's hard to follow what you are asking as the question and the code provided don't seem to have anything to do with each other.

Comment: All this already advised in at least two other cross-postings https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-help-please.1246773/ and http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?71151-VBA-Code-to-call-another-VBA-function-when-certain-cells-match-a-given-criteria

Comment: Hi all, OK, I am still struggling with this and have a weird situation, I'm not sure how I respond to the individual comment left, its not clear from looking at this web page, where I go in order to reply, it doesn't seem to have a 'reply button' visible against each comment, so I am going to amend the main original thread with latest information

Comment: *Below is the whole code* ? There are no `End Select` to the `Case` statements. By "SaveButtonAir_Click is in the forms module" do you mean as an event handler for the CFSCollectionAir form. "when the user selects CFS Loading, I wish to call my Sub CFSCollectionAir" - isn't CFSCollectionAir the form name ?

Comment: Thank you CDP1802, I have managed to obtain corrected code now for this project, I need to close this thread off but cannot see where I do this from looking at the main screen.